# Can I install PHP on a Chumby One?

Tags: php, arm

I'm enjoying hacking my [Chumby One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chumby). However, I'd prefer if I could run PHP on it. I have `perl` and `python` installed.

Does anyone know if I can compile PHP for it or if there is a ready made distro for Chumby that includes PHP?

Answer (score 1):

[PHP packages exist in Debian armel](http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/armel/php5) at least. If you install Debian, you should get php, properly integrated, as usual. There may be missing pieces or other traps, of course. I'm sure Netwinder/qube users and other arm boxes have run php.

It seems Debian has been a [second class citizen](http://forum.chumby.com/viewtopic.php?id=6411) only (chroot) in Chumbies. I've been hoping to do a full native install some day, but haven't had the time to try yet.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does compile on ARM, provided you have a compiler for it.

Comment: I have a toolchain for the chumby but there are many missing pieces. I can't imagine I'm the only person on the planet who wants to use php on the arm platform. I just have to find who's done it already. I tried cross compiling on an x86 and there are so many missing pieces I'm lost.

Comment: Lots have. But possibly not on that specific ARM version.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found: [Cross-compiled THTTPD server with PHP runs fine, but no PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817685/cross-compiled-thttpd-server-with-php-runs-fine-but-no-php).

I'm not sure if it will work on Chumby, but it should provide a start since you are aiming to run PHP on an ARM processor and this person successfully got it running.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to compile myself but I'll give it a shot. The question you refer to did have the solution for getting php to run.